# Game Boy GPU and Nintendo logo

Tags: c, gpu, emulation, hardware, gameboy

I am trying to develop my own GB emulator, but I am having some trouble implementing the GPU. I have decided to start printing the Nintendo startup logo, unsuccessfully. Apparently, the problem is the byte order, according to this already solved question: [How to decode the Nintendo logo from gameboy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119904/how-to-decode-the-nintendo-logo-from-gameboy). However, I do not understand the criteria followed to sort the hex string. Could somebody, please, enlighten me? Is this sorting process a need in the whole emulator (for actual game emulation, I mean. I did not notice it was when I was reading the CPU manual)?

Comment: There is no sorting. According to that question’s responses, each bit is a 4×1 block of pixels.

Comment: If this is off-topic, feel free to send it to [retrocomputing.se]. It appears just to be a request for clarification for the previous question though.

Comment: Look at the order in which the original input hex values appear in the answer. It's not left-to-right, it's top-to-bottom, per nibble, and then per block with a predetermined fixed height.

Comment: Okay, I get how the values are displayed. But does it only take place in the startup, with the logo, or should every tile/sprite presented this way when the emulator fetches video info from memory?

Comment: @HastatusXXI, everything in gameboy is made up of tiles - background, window, sprites. For all of them you use the same kind of decoding when displaying these tiles. The actual addresses of tile patterns and tile maps are different. As well as how exactly you display them on the screen.